# Renumber reference variables in text columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, plpgsql

### Background

For a data entry project, a user can enter variables using a short-hand notation:

```
"Pour i1 into a flask."
"Warm the flask to 25 degrees C."
"Add 1 drop of i2 to the flask."
"Immediately seek cover."
```

In this case `i1` and `i2` are reference variables, where the number refers to an ingredient. The text strings are in the `INSTRUCTION` table, the ingredients the `INGREDIENT` table.

Each ingredient has a sequence number for sorting purposes.

### Problem

Users may rearrange the ingredient order, which adversely changes the instructions. For example, the ingredient order might look as follows, initially:

```
seq | label
1   | water
2   | sodium
```

The user adds another ingredient:

```
seq | label
1   | water
2   | sodium
3   | francium
```

The user reorders the list:

```
seq | label
1   | water
2   | francium
3   | sodium
```

At this point, the following line is now incorrect:

```
"Add 1 drop of i2 to the flask."
```

The `i2` must be renumbered (because ingredient #2 was moved to position #3) to point to the original reference variable:

```
"Add 1 drop of i3 to the flask."
```

#### Updated Details

This is a simplified version of the problem. The full problem can have lines such as:

```
"Add 1 drop of i2 to the o3 of i1."
```

Where `o3` is an object (flask), and `i1` and `i2` are water and sodium, respectively.

### Table Structure

The ingredient table is structured as follows:

```
id | seq | label
```

The instruction table is structured as follows:

```
step
```

### Algorithm

The algorithm I have in mind:

1. Repeat for all `step`s that match the expression `'\mi([0-9]+)'`:
2. Break the step into word tokens.
3. For each token:

   1. If the numeric portion of the token matches the old sequence number, replace it with the new sequence number.
   2. Recombine the tokens and update the instruction.
   3. Update the ingredient number.

#### Update

The algorithm may be incorrect as written. There could be two reference variables that must change. Consider before:

```
seq | label
1   | water
2   | sodium
3   | caesium
4   | francium
```

And after (swapping sodium and caesium):

```
seq | label
1   | water
2   | caesium
3   | sodium
4   | francium
```

Every `i2` in every step must become `i3`; similarly `i3` must become `i2`. So

```
"Add 1 drop of i2 to the flask, but absolutely do not add i3."
```

Becomes:

```
"Add 1 drop of i3 to the flask, but absolutely do not add i2."
```

### Code

The code to perform the first two parts of the algorithm resembles:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  renumber_steps(
    p_ingredient_id integer,
    p_old_sequence integer,
    p_new_sequence integer )
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  v_tokens text[];

BEGIN
  FOR v_tokens IN
    SELECT
      t.tokens
    FROM (
      SELECT
        regexp_split_to_array( step, '\W' ) tokens,
        regexp_matches( step, '\mi([0-9]+)' ) matches
      FROM
        instruction
      ) t
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', v_tokens;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

### Question

What is a more efficient way to solve this problem (i.e., how would you eliminate the looping constructs), possibly leveraging PostgreSQL-specific features, without a major revision to the data model?

Thank you!

#### System Details

PostgreSQL 9.1.2.

Comment: Does the instruction table have a foreign key to the ingredient table?

Comment: No. It is not a 1:1 relationship; each step can refer to multiple ingredients (and multiple objects, but that's a detail I've eliminated to simplify the problem).

Comment: So how are steps and ingredients linked then?

Comment: ingredient `->` ingredient group `->` recipe; instruction `->` instruction group `->` recipe. It is an indirect relation.

Comment: why the pl/sql tag?  this is postreSQL no?  should be PL/pgSQL maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care that you don't change ingredients and `seq` numbers back and forth. I introduce a temporary prefix for ingredients and negative numbers for `seq` for that purpose and exchange them for permanent values when all is done.

Could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION renumber_steps(_old int[], _new int[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _prefix     CONSTANT text := ' i';    -- prefix, incl. leading space
    _new_prefix CONSTANT text := ' ###';  -- temp prefix, incl. leading space
    i           int;
    o           text;
    n           text;
BEGIN

IF array_upper(_old,1) <> array_upper(_new,1) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Array length mismatch!';
END IF;

FOR i IN 1  .. array_upper(_old,1) LOOP
    IF _old[i] <> _new[i] THEN
        o := _prefix || _old[i] || ' ';        -- leading and trailing blank!
        -- new instruction are temporarily prefixed with new_marker
        n := _new_prefix || _new[i]  || ' ';

        UPDATE instruction
        SET    step = replace(step, o, n)      -- replace all instances
        WHERE  step ~~ ('%' || o || '%');

        UPDATE ingredient
        SET    seq = _new[i] * -1              -- temporarily negative
        WHERE  seq = _old[i];
    END IF;
END LOOP;

-- finally replace temp. prefix
UPDATE instruction
SET    step = replace(step, _new_prefix, _prefix)
WHERE  step ~~ ('%' || _new_prefix || '%');

-- .. and temp. negative seq numbers
UPDATE ingredient
SET    seq = seq * -1
WHERE  seq < 0;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT renumber_steps('{2,3,4}'::int[], '{4,3,2}'::int[]);
```

The algorithm requires ...
  ... that ingredients in the steps are delimited by spaces.
  ... that there are no permanent negative seq numbers.

`_old` and `_new` are ARRAYs of the old and new `instruction.seq` of ingredients that change position. The length of both arrays has to match, or an exception will be raised.  It can contain `seq` that don't change. Nothing will happen to those.

Requires PostgreSQL **9.1** or later.

Comment: Thank you Erwin. The problem is a little simpler as only one item can be swapped at one time, which effectively changes two items. However, such a general solution that you propose might also handle the case when the user deletes an ingredient.

Comment: @DaveJarvis; My demo call does exactly that: swap position of two items. The third one in the middle remains unchanged and is supposed to demonstrate that the function can handle that, too. The level of sophistication is needed for just two items that trade places.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is problematic... you should have the "real name (`id`)" (`i1`, `o3` etc.) FIXED after creation and have a second field in the `ingredient` table providing the "sorting". The user enters the "sorting name" and you immediately replace it with the "real name" (`id`) on saving the entered data into the `step` table.

When you read it from the `step` table you just replace/map the "real name" (`id`) with the current "sorting name" for display purposes if need be...

This way you don't have to change the data already in the `step` table for everytime someone changes the sorting which is a complex and expensive operation IMHO - it is prone to concurrency problems too...

The above option reduces the whole problem to a mapping operiton (table `ingredient`) on INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT (table `step`) for the one entry currently worked on - it doesn't mess with any other entries already there.

Comment: The system is XML + XSL driven; the reference variables (`i1`, etc.) are converted to corresponding XML tags, which are indirectly keyed to the reference ingredient list (elsewhere in the XML). These XML tags are then transformed via XSL. (Also, there are i18n constraints and other linguistic issues in effect.) Changing the model really isn't an option at this time. I greatly appreciate the suggestion, though.